# Cant find @CucumberOptions

Tags: cucumber, spring-boot-test, junit-jupiter

I have tried several options to create a CucumberTestRunner which I believe from lots of reading is required to run a cucumber test.

I have even tried using code suggested by AI but always get the same problem, **Cannot resolve symbol 'CucumberOptions'**

Have tried versions of the dependencies always the same result.

Using IntelliJ on Windows 10, jdk 21, Gradle 8.6 with Kotlin DSL and currently the following dependencies:

```
implementation("io.cucumber:cucumber-spring:7.15.0")
implementation("io.cucumber:cucumber-java:7.15.0")
implementation("io.cucumber:cucumber-junit-platform-engine:7.15.0")


testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.10.2")
testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.10.2")

testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:3.2.3")
```

Any idea where the stupid error is?

Comment: `@CucumberOptions` is for JUnit 4. You are using JUnit 5. You'll want to copy the https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-java-skeleton and then read https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/tree/main/cucumber-junit-platform-engine from top to bottom.

Comment: Thanks, that fixes the problem.
As expected I had done all the right things not just all at once
Thanks again.